# Im trying to fit the model using the fit function but its causing None Type Attribute error

Tags: python, cross-entropy

Here is the section of code

```
#Compililng the model
opt = Adam(lr = INIT_LR, decay = INIT_LR/ EPOCHS)
model = model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics = ["accuracy"])

#training the head network
H = model.fit(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size = BS),
             steps_per_epoch = len(trainX)// BS,
             validation_data=(testX, testY),
             validation_steps = len(testX)//BS,
             epochs = EPOCHS)
```

Here is the error that happens when I run this code

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

What could I be doing wrong? Kindly help

Comment: I believe that `compile()` method doesn't return anything therefore when you assign `model` to a return value you get `None`.

Comment: So should I instead write it as compile.fit() ?

Comment: How should I put it or what should I do in this case?

Comment: Just do `model.compile()` but without `model=`